# Is there a way to make this PHP code more effecient?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make some "dynamic" links on a page. Basically I want to drop the link for the page that I am on. (eg. if I am on the home page I don't want a home link displayed but if I am on the FAQ page the home link will be displayed and the FAQ link will not.) This code works the way I want it to work, I just think that there has to be a better way that doesn't duplicate so much code, but in my limited programming experience I can's see it.

```
<div class= "links">
<?php
    switch ($page_title) {
            case 'Home':
            echo '<p class= "who">'.
                    '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="1"><img src=     "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
                 '</p>';
            echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                    '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;


    case 'Who is BeeCharmer':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;

    case 'Contact Us':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "who">'.
                '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;

    case 'What We Do':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "who">'.
                '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;

    case 'FAQ':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "who">'.
                '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;

    case 'Photo Gallery':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "who">'.
                '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;

    case 'Pollination Services':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "who">'.
                '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pay">'.
                 '<a href="payus.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;

    case 'Pay Us':
        echo '<p class= "home">'.
                '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
              '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "who">'.
                '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src= "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "contact">'.
                '<a href="contact.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "what">'.
                '<a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class ="FAQ">'.
                '<a href="faq.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pics">'.
                '<a href="gallery.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        echo '<p class= "pollination">'.
                 '<a href="pollination.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>'.
             '</p>';
        break;
}
```

?>

Here is the CSS that styles it.

```
div.links { width: 40%;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 280px;
                    left: 2%;  }
        div.links p img { border: none; 
                          position: relative;
                          top: -29px;
                          left: 5px; }
        div.links p { background-image: url("../images/yellowSlidingDoorleft.png"),
                                        url("../images/yellowSlidingDoorRight.png"),
                                        url("../images/yellowSlidingDoorMiddle.png");
                      background-position: top left, top right, top center;
                      background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat; 
                      height: 38px;
                      width: 520px;
                      border: none;
                      overflow: hidden; }
        /*div.links p.home { position: relative;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.who { position: relative;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.contact { position: relative;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.what { position: relative;
                top: 150px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.FAQ { position: relative;
                top: 200px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.pics { position: relative;
                top: 250px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.pollination { position: relative;
                top: 300px;
                left: 0px; }
        div.links p.pay { position: relative;
                top: 350px;
                left: 0px; }*/
        div.links p:hover img { position: relative;
                top: 5px;
                left: 5px; }
        div.links p:hover { background-image: url("../images/blackSlidingDoorleft.png"),
                                              url("../images/blackSlidingDoorRight.png"),
                                              url("../images/blackSlidingDoorMiddle.png");
                            background-position: top left, top right, top center;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat; }
```

Any help that you guys can give would be really appreciated

Comment: Why not just save every link in an array. Loop over the array and check for the page title to skip the link accordingly.

Comment: Better you had written in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, realizing that your current solution is not dynamic.  Many inexperienced programmers seem to make the mistake of using `switch` statements in this kind of situation, when what you really want is dynamic code accessing arrays, as @Torsten brought up.  You also don't need repetitive `if` statements as in PeterVR's answer, or repetitive function calls as in DaiYoukai's.  Putting the repetition into an array gives you a flexible, dynamic structure that you can access and manipulate programatically.

Try something like this (add any additional key-value pairs you need to the arrays):

```
$nav_items = array(

  'home' => array(

    'class' => 'home',

    'href' => "index.php",

    'src' => "HomePage"

    'label' => "Home Page"

  ),
  // home


  'whois' => array(

    'class' => 'who',

    'href' => "...",

    'src' => "..."

    'label' => "..."

  ),
  // whois

  ...

);
// $nav_items


$nav_sets = array(

  'home' => array(

    'whois',

    'contact',

    'whatwedo',

    'faq',

    'gallery',

    'pollination',

    'payus'

  ),


  'whois' => array(

    'home',

    'contact',

    'whatwedo',

    'faq',

    'pics',

    'pollination'

  ),

  ...

);
// $nav_sets


foreach ( $nav_sets[ $page_title ] as $nav_id ) {

  $nav_item = $nav_items[ $nav_id ];

  echo <<<DOCHERE

<p class="{$nav_item[ 'class' ]}">
<a href="{$nav_item[ 'href' ]}" tabindex="1"><img src="images/{$nav_item[ 'src' ]}.png" alt= "{$nav_item[ 'label' ]}" /></a>
</p>

DOCHERE;

}
// foreach
```

This doesn't exactly match up with your use of `$page_title` -- I'd just put a variable in each page, something like `$nav_id`, that matches the keys in the `$nav_items` and `$nav_sets` arrays.

Here you have one copy of the data for each navigation item, which may appear on any number of pages, and one template for generating HTML output for all of the items.  That eliminates the problematic duplication.  This example includes explicit sets of items, in case you need that much control.  If you just need to display all items on each page except for the item corresponding to the current page, then you could just loop over `$nav_items` and exclude the current page.

I also eliminated the horrendous use of string concatentation for building up the output.

Comment: I think you are correct. This may not be the easiest solution for me, but it appears to be the best. I have tried the multiple IF statement and it works fine but I don't think it is the most efficient. Thank you for your time and knowledge

Comment: This is what I finally went with. It took me a little bit to actually figure out how it was working but in the end I got it. Thank you again for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @beewrangler. Glad you found the time to check it out. I think it'll be a good investment of time as you'll have some more techniques at your disposal in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
<div class= "links">
<?php
    if ( $page_title != 'home') {
       echo '<p class= "home">'.
            '<a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>'.
            '</p>';
    }
    if ( $page_title != 'Who is BeeCharmer') {
       echo '<p class= "who">'.
            '<a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src=     "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>'.
            '</p>';
    }

//and so on...
```

Comment: incorporate the function from @DaiYoukai in this solution, and it would be even more efficient. I'm not a big fan of switch statemants...

Answer (score 1):

It would be far more efficient to simply include the list of links for that page as HTML on that page, if you're literally creating a separate list for every page anyway (as `switch($page_title)` seems to imply).

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that adding or removing links to be extremely time consuming. Using an include allows me to edit only one page.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the redundant HTML code by way of a function. (Works in this case because all your links are formatted exactly the same, just certain elements such as class, href, tabindex, imgsrc and img alt are different)

```
function displayLinks ($pClass, $aHref, $tabIndex, $imgSRC, $alt) {
echo '<p class="' . $pClass . '"><a href="' . $aHref . '.php" tabindex="' . $tabIndex . '"><img src="' . $imgSRC . '" alt= "' . $alt . '" /></a>'</p>';
}
```

and would be called like

```
displayLinks('who','whois',1,'images/WhoIs.png','Who is BeeCharmer');
displayLinks('contact','contact',2,'images/ContactUs.png','Who is ContactUs');
```

and so on

Though since most of your links in the entirety are the same I would go a step further and keep the conditional for only the the varying links.

```
what, faq, pics, pollination, pay
```

exist on all except Home and Contact us. So they need on not be repeated or enclosed in their own if

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, and probably should ever have to directly echo HTML like that.  Since I take it this is a view file, I'd put the nav into its own file and then do `require('nav_links.php');` where the links currently are, with the content of `nav_links.php` looking like this

`nav_links.php`

```
<div class= "links">
<?php if($page_title != 'home'): ?>
<p class= "home">.
    <a href="index.php" tabindex="1"><img src= "images/HomePage.png"  alt= "Home Page" /></a>.
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title != 'Who is BeeCharmer'): ?>
 <p class= "who">
    <a href="whois.php" tabindex="2"><img src=     "images/WhoIs.png" alt= "Who is BeeCharmer" /></a>
 </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title != 'Contact Us'): ?>
 <p class= "contact">
        <a href="contact.php" tabindex="3"><img src= "images/ContactUs.png" alt= "Contact Us" /></a>
 </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title !=  'What We Do'): ?>
<p class= "what">
    <a href="whatwedo.php" tabindex="4"><img src= "images/WhatWeDo.png" alt= "What Does BeeCharmer Do" /></a>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title != 'FAQ'): ?>
 <p class ="FAQ">
    <a href="faq.php" tabindex="5"><img src= "images/FAQ.png" alt= "Frequently Asked Questions" /></a>
 </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title != 'Photo Gallery'): ?>
 <p class= "pics">
    <a href="gallery.php" tabindex="6"><img src= "images/gallery.png" alt= "Photo Gallery" /></a>
 </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title != 'Pollination Services'): ?>
 <p class= "pollination">
     <a href="pollination.php" tabindex="7"><img src= "images/Pollination.png" alt= "Pollination Services" /></a>
 </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($page_title != 'Pay Us'): ?>
 <p class= "pay">.
     <a href="payus.php" tabindex="8"><img src= "images/PayUs.png" alt= "Pay BeeCharmer" /></a>
 </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This seems like the easiest for me to implement. Thank you for your time and expertise.